# When does MS_MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED error occur and what does it mean?

Tags: html, html5-video, media-player

I searched for the following IE specific MediaError code but couldn't find anything.

```
declare var MediaError: {
    prototype: MediaError;
    new(): MediaError;
    MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: number;
    MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: number;
    MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: number;
    MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: number;
    **MS_MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: number;** //This has error code = 5. What does this error mean?
}
```

I looked it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaError but there are only 4 error codes listed.

Comment: I get the same thing here: https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-drm-test-player/ when I load in edge on a windows 10 virtual machine. I'm guessing ms disallows playready drm on virtual machines.

Comment: @luke-chinworth Also happens on a physical Windows 10 desktop, so not related to virtualisation

Answer (score 0):

It's related EME(Encrypted Media Extensions)
It has been written about MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED in v0.1.
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/eme-v0.1/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html#error-codes

(I couldn't find it in latest version strangely.)
https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/

You can see msExtendedCode in object of MediaError.
It may help to know error details. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MsExtendedCode

However, I couldn't find error code list on public.
You may need to ask Microsoft Support.

Comment: I found msExtendedCode is related PlayReady's error code.
I think it's not in public.